# How do I create a site content scrolling like in these examples?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Notice how the content scrolls on these example sites (I'm not affiliated with any of them, I just found them randomly):

http://www.nikebetterworld.com/
http://www.esetsmartsecurity.com/

It's like there are 2 layers scrolling at different speeds. How would I go about doing such a site/content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow. Especially ESET's page amazed me because it seems to run better than Nike's.

As far as I can see they're using various jQuery plugins like:

- jQuery inView plugin - https://github.com/zuk/jquery.inview
- jQuery scrollTo plugin - http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html
- jQuery LocalScroll plugin - http://flesler.blogspot.com/2009/03/jquerylocalscroll-127-released.html
- etc.

So they run javascript and change elements' opacity, positions and background positions while user scrolls the document. Scrolling can be done manually or clicking on dots (that uses LocalScroll plugin).

**Amazing stuff**. +1 for pointing it out.

> Although Similar approach, Nike uses different scripts to accomplish a very similar effect.

Answer (score 3):

it's called parallax 
here's a jquery plugin for it
http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html

how to create a parallax background effect
http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/create-a-funky-parallax-background-effect-using-jquery/